# How to get the integer part from a string using regex

Tags: regex, string, integer

```
string $str  = "hello768gonf123";
```

How do I get the numbers at the end (i.e. `123`) using regex?

Comment: Are there always going to be three digits? Are they always going to be at the end of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the integer is always found at the end of the string(`hello768gonf123`), you can use:

```
(\d+)$
```

If you want to capture the integer closer to the end (`123` from `hello768gonf123foo`) you can use:

```
(\d+)\D*$
```

Answer (score 1):

The regexp ".*([0-9]+)" matches anything followed by a series of one or more digits, and returns the digits as the (only) capture group.